# How to assign new column to existing DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas. I'm trying to add new columns to my existing DataFrame but It's not getting assigned don't know why can anyone explain me what I'm missing this is what i tried

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"test":["mkt1","mkt2","mkt3"],
                         "test2":["cty1","cty2","cty3"]})
print("Before",df.columns)
df.assign(test3="Hello")
print("After",df.columns)
```

**Output**

```
Before Index(['test', 'test2'], dtype='object')
After Index(['test', 'test2'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: `assign` does not occur `inplace`.

Comment: `df = df.assign(test3="Hello")`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris ```df = df.assign(test3="Hello")``` check I've added in between two print functions where should place it can you provide a solution for it

Comment: sorry what is the question? You just need to replace ```df.assign(test3="Hello")``` to ```df = df.assign(test3="Hello")```

Comment: Hello @sophocles It's solved my problem thanks ❤️️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas `assign` method returns a new modified dataframe with a new column, it does not modify it in place.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"test":["mkt1","mkt2","mkt3"],
                         "test2":["cty1","cty2","cty3"]})
print("Before",df.columns)
df = df.assign(test3="Hello") # <--- Note the variable reassingment
print("After",df.columns)
```

Comment: Hello @BSP I've got solution by **sophocles** but thanks for your answer ❤️️

Comment: @ I see he commented just before me. Anyway, the important idea behind your question is that pandas dataframes methods do not modify them in place but return a new modified copy. That is what I wanted to explain.